# Retrieve query column as row

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following columns:

```
BillNo   -- Integer
BillDate -- DateTime
Qty      -- decimal
ItemName -- varchar
```

I want to retrieve results in this format:

```
**ITEMNAME...JAN-2011.....FEB-2011....MAR-2011** 
ITEM1 ......... 20 ..............19................18
ITEM2 ......... 23 ..............10................9
```

I tried this query which is showing correct results but I want to convert third column to a row with distinct values:

```
SELECT ITEMNAME, SUM(QTY), DATE_FORMAT(BILLDATE,'%M-%Y') FROM BILLITEMS
GROUP BY BILLDATE
ORDER BY YEAR(BILLDATE) DESC, MONTH(BILLDATE), ITEMNAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use query below but it will work for a specific year

```
SELECT ITEMNAME, year_bill, SUM(jan), SUM(feb), .... from (
    select case when MONTH(BILLDATE) = 1 then QTY else 0 end as jan,
    case when MONTH(BILLDATE) = 2 then QTY else 0 end as feb,
    case when MONTH(BILLDATE) = 3 then QTY else 0 end as mar,
    ITEMNAME,
    YEAR(BILLDATE) as year_bill
from BILLITEMS) as temp
GROUP BY ITEMNAME, year_bill
```

Comment: But the year and month is not fixed.

Comment: I removed third month, but it is giving error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select case when MONTH(BILLDATE) = 2 then QTY else 0 end as feb,
    ITEMNAME, ' at line 3

Comment: Most of the QTY displayed are 0. It is not showing correct results.

Comment: Could you provide result of the query, test data and expecetd reuslt. Without thise it's hard to make answer.

Comment: I think I should mail you the sample database.